# django model with foreign key to one of two possible models

Tags: django, django-models

I have a two models that are similar, but not exactly the same.  Here's the best abstraction of the problem that I can come up with.

```
class Cat(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    breed = models.TextField()

class Dog(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    color = models.TextField()
```

And now I need to make another model like this.

```
class Pet(models.Model):
    favoriteFood = models.TextField()
    isCat = models.BooleanField()
    animal = models.ForeignKey(?????????)
```

My problem is that the animal field of the Pet model is going to be a foreign key to either the Cat or the Dog model depending on the value of isCat.  How can I do that?

Now, I know this is an unusual/awkward schema in the first place, but I wasn't involved in its creation and I can't change it.  I just have to support it.  I'm writing these models for an existing database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should see [Generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#id1).

Comment: I'm sure this is the correct answer, but I ended up going a different way with the models altogether.

Answer (score 1):

[Generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#id1) is a direct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another option for this use case is: [django-polymorphic](https://github.com/django-polymorphic/django-polymorphic) :)