# How to connect one django model to many other models?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I'm trying to develop a property management system. I've created the bedroom and bathroom models. In each bedroom and bathroom I need to add lighting, climatization and entertainment models. I've created those models but I'm not sure if I should create another model like "Lighting_Bedroom" and use the ForeignKeys pointing to both models, or if there's another way to do this.

```
// Bedroom Model
class Bedroom(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(db_column='Type', choices=BEDROOM_TYPE_CHOICES, max_length=50)
    bed_dimensions = models.CharField(db_column='Bed_Dimension', choices=BED_DIMENSION_CHOICES, max_length=30)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True)
    ensuite = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    notes = models.CharField(db_column='Notes', max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

// Bathroom Model
class Bathroom(models.Model):
    sink = models.CharField(db_column='Sink', choices=SINK_BATHROOM_CHOICES, max_length=50)
    shower = models.CharField(db_column='Shower', choices=SHOWER_BATHROOM_CHOICES, max_length=50)
    tower_rail = models.CharField(db_column='Tower_Rail', choices=TOWER_RAIL_BATHROOM_CHOICES, max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True)
    toilet = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    bidet = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    bath = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    extractor_fan = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    notes = models.CharField(db_column='Notes', max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

// Properties

class Lighting(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(db_column='Type', choices=LIGHTING_TYPE_CHOICES, max_length=30)
    bulb_type = models.CharField(db_column='Bulb_Type',  max_length=30)

class Climatization(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(db_column='Type', choices=CLIMATIZATION_TYPE_CHOICES, max_length=30)
    use = models.CharField(db_column='Use', choices=CLIMATIZATION_USE_CHOICES, max_length=30)
    brand = models.CharField(db_column='Brand',  max_length=30)
    model = models.CharField(db_column='Model',  max_length=50)
    remote_control = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    notes = models.CharField(db_column='Notes', max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
```

So far I didn't create the third model to connect both models cause I've read about ManyToManyField but I'm not shure if that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an option to have a `RoomFitting` model that has a `OneToOneField` in each room type and then your `Lighting` model can have a foreign key to this model.

```
class Bedroom(models.Model):
    fittings = OneToOneField(RoomFitting)

class Lighting(models.Model):
    fitting = ForeignKey(RoomFitting)
```

It all depends on how the class can be used and is intended to be used, not all lighting is suitably rated for use within a bathroom for example

Comment: I came up with an idea from your comment, could you please check out the answer that I've posted? Thank you!!

Comment: @LuisSilva - Your answer has nothing to do with your question

Comment: I've deleted it, I'll figure out another of doing it then

Comment: In found this post that is almost what I'm looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122597/django-model-with-foreign-key-to-one-of-two-possible-models